# Prove the taylor series of $ \cos(2z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

First i turned $$\cos(2z) = \frac{e^{2iz} + e^{-2iz}}{2}$$, then using the taylor series of $$e^{z}$$I calculated the taylor series of both arguments.
$$\frac{e^{2iz}}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(i)^{n}2^{n-1}z^{n}}{n!}$$
$$\frac{e^{-2iz}}{2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-i)^{n}2^{n-1}z^{n}}{n!}$$
From this stage i dont know how to continue.
Is my way to the solution is right?

Comment: you are on the right track.  cos(z) and the exponential functions are entire, so their Taylor series will always converge and you can add/subtract them.  There is a part in each of the summations that can be simplified, what is it?

Comment: No idea which part you meant...

Comment: what is i^n can only be one of 4 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(i)^n+(-i)^n=e^{\frac{in\pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{-in\pi}{2}}=2\cos{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}.$$

Comment: so the complete answer will be: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}z^{n}cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}{n!}$$ ??

Comment: Yes:    $$ \cos(2z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(i)^{n}2^{n-1}z^{n}}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-i)^{n}2^{n-1}z^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}\cdot 2^{n}\cdot z^{n}}{n!}$$